# Eclipse won't Launch: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: url

Tags: java, eclipse

It was working last night, and then this morning, after no changes what so ever when I try and launch Eclipse it immediately cuts to a popup box:

"An error has occurred. See the log file ".

So i open the log file to find:

```
!SESSION 2019-06-14 08:55:20.570 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-06-14 08:55:22.135
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: url
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeImages(Workbench.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

I tried searching google for help with this, but to no avail.

I don't even understand what the error is, never mind how I might go about fixing it.

EDIT:

So i managed to fix this myself by re-installing eclipse. I still don't know what caused the error. So the question has now become - what causes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're sorry you ran into this rather disruptive problem - this issue affects Eclipse Neon users who have the DevStyle Icon Designer installed.

You need to delete the `com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.icon.designer_1.11.0.201906121516` plugin, please see [this post](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/unable-to-launch-eclipse-neon-nosuchfielderror-url/) for further details and specific instructions on the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have any eclipse marketplace themes active? I got the same error today as well. It was fixed my removing Eclipse themes.